# forem gem for rails giving issues with custom authentication Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rubygems, forum

After installing forem when I do localhost:3000/forums this error pops up

> NoMethodError in Forem/forums#index
>
> undefined method `users_path' for #<#:0xc620c6c>

This is my _new.html.haml, It is indicating that the error is coming in the line where I have used =semantic_form_for

```
.container
    .row
        .twelve.columns
            .signupModal.reveal-modal
                =semantic_form_for(@user = User.new, :validate => true) do |f|
                    =f.inputs do
                        =f.input :email, :label => "Email"
                        =f.input :password, :label => "Password"
```

Here is the code for route:-

```
resources :users

  match '/signup', :to => 'users#new'

  resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
  match '/signin', :to => 'sessions#new' 
  match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'
```

It is supposed to be pretty simple I dont know where I am missing it.

P.S:- I do not get any issues when I run the app without going to /forums all the paths are working fine in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting "Rails3 In Action" book:

> This is happening because your engine is using the application’s
>   layout and is trying to reference admin_root_path method from inside
>   the engine, rather than the one that’s defined in the application. To
>   fix this, you’ll need to first call main_app for these routing helpers
>   and then call the helpers on that.

Replace users_path with main_app.users_path and it should work.